# Null values for calculated members in case statement (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

i am a beginner in MDX. I want to show the number of a month January --> 1.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Mnr]
 AS CASE [Measures].[Time].[Calendar].[Month].Currentmember.Name
   WHEN 'January' THEN '1'
   WHEN 'February' THEN '2'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END
```

I get only null values and can not find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to replace `[Measures].[Time].[Calendar].[Month].Currentmember.Name` with `[Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name`

The CurrentMember function operates on a hierarchy not a level. And Measures is wrong as the Time dimension isn’t a child of Measures.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution still get zero values.

Comment: @Detlef7able please provide more info. Can you describe your report or PivotTable? Can you screenshot the dimension designer pane in visual studio?

Comment: [link](https://abload.de/img/screenshot_zeite1kns.png)
[link](https://abload.de/img/screenshot_zeit_attrio5j17.png)


The exchange of english and german terms is not the problem.

Comment: Is the data only German or setup to show in the user’s language? Did you say March or März? I believe the .Name function returns the default language while .Member_Caption returns the current user’s language. What client tool are you using?

Comment: The data is in German. It should show unknown because I test it at first only with January and February. I reversed the expression only to show it here. Visual Studio 2019 ,Analysis-Services Project.

Comment: Okay sorry i had a spelling mistake yet by the Calendar - attribute. But I have still a question why I have to remove the [Month] - attribute?

Comment: @Detlef7able because CurrentMember only works on a hierarchy not a level

Comment: Okay thank you how could I access the year in my example?

Comment: @Detlef7able through the attribute hierarchy: `[Time].[Year].CurrentMember.Name`